# how to read an array of objects from a json config file using scala

Tags: json, scala

my json file looks like :

```
{
    "array":[
        {
            "name": ["na"],
            "age": "15"
        },
        {
            "name": ["aa","bb"],
            "age": "12"
        },
        {
            "name": ["rr,yy"],
            "age": "22"
        },
}    ]
```

i try to read a config file and to get the name and age

I tried this but i didn't get a result:

```
val defaultSvaipConfig = ConfigFactory.load()

val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("config.json"))

val pathFileConfig = config.getConfig("array")
```

I tried also this :

```
     ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("application.json"))
     config.getConfigList("mapConfig").asScala.map { conf =>
      val name = config.getString("name")
      val value = config.getString("age")
      ConfigData(name, age)
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a config file. Why don't you just read the file as a String and use Circe or something like that to parse it?

Comment: Typesafe config support that

Comment: @cchantep: i don't see how can i do that. I tried but it don't have my result

Comment: Your brackets do not match, but perhaps that is a cut-and-paste error. What error do you get?

Comment: use gson will help

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for but for something like this I like to use circe(https://github.com/circe/circe-config):

```
    import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    import io.circe.generic.auto._
    import io.circe.config.syntax._
    case class Something(name: List[String], age: String)
    case class WholeConfig(array: List[Something])
    val config: Either[Error, WholeConfig] = ConfigFactory.load.as[WholeConfig]
```